# python tkinter IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python

Пишу мини-вирус на питоне, помогите пж с ошибкой. В цикле `while True` идет проверка на то, открыто ли окно диспетчера задач, после чего идет апдейт ткинтер окон, но вылезает ошибка
`IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`, хотя с отступами там все нормально, как и должно быть, ниже я прикрепил код цикла.

```
while True:
    if len(pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title_re="Диспетчер задач")) != 0:
        os.system("shutdown /r /t 0")

    
    root1.update_idletasks()
                          #^
    # ошибка находится тут |
    root1.update()
    root2.update_idletasks()
    root2.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Вот код ошибки:

```
C:\Users\User>python C:\Users\User\Desktop\Trojan.Nazar.Win32\Main.py
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Trojan.Nazar.Win32\Main.py", line 35
    root1.update_idletasks()
                           ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

С отступами там я думаю, питон не понимает, что `root1.update_idletasks()` идет отдельно от условия `if`, поетому, помогите, как отделить вызов функции от условия.

Comment: Вам нужно привести код который воспроизводит ошибку.

Comment: То что есть у меня не запустится из-за того что нет инициализации некоторых объектов.

Comment: Советую изучить хотя бы пару вопросов по этой ошибке на этом сайте. В них наверняка найдётся решение проблемы.

Comment: 1. Я привел конкретное место где происходит ошибка.

Comment: 2. Всё уже инициализировано

Comment: 3. Я пробовал найти на всех форумах, пока-что неинашел

Comment: Извините, но за вредоносный код сразу минус автоматом и совершенно не хочется помогать :/

Answer (score 0):

Вы не нашли ошибку в отступах, но стоит проверить, если вы используете пробелы, то поставили недостаточное их количество, или наоборот, если используете `Tab`, то поставили прообел.

Comment: я все переставлял, не таб не пробелы не помогли